# Windows don't boot after Ubuntu installation in VMware on a physical disk

Tags: boot, windows-7, uefi, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu in VMware (Windows 7) on a physical disk. It's a secondary disk, not a partition.
All worked, no problems. Then i restarted Windows and Windows failed to boot and then Ubuntu booted.
Windows don't boot until i remove the secondary disk.

Ubuntu uses UEFI and i think that is the problem, but i am not sure.
That would mean that as far as there is a second disk in your computer, windows can't boot.

But it's a different disk, and i am not using grub to boot windows. Windows is still the first boot device. And i don't want to boot Ubuntu from the BIOS att all. I just want to start ubuntu through VMware.

Any ideas why windows fails to boot when there is another disk that has a MBR even if that is not in the boot list of the BIOS?

**Edit:**
I don't want to boot Ubuntu and I don't want a dual boot.
I just want to boot Windows while the Ubuntu disk is connected, so I can later start VMware in Windows that is configured to load that Ubuntu from a separate disk.
But windows don't boot as long as the Ubuntu disk is connected. It's only connected at a SATA port, its is not configured as a boot option, only Windows is.

But I think that is not possible with UEFI (some security thing?) but I thought I ask for help before I reinstall Windows without UEFI...

Comment: If your device indees uses UEFI and your Windows isn't installed in UEFI mode, it may indeed be that there is a second boot device list for UEFI, which may be preferred over the Legacy BIOS boot list (at least this is the case with my HP ProBook)

Comment: @the_Seppi my Windows is installed in UEFI mode and only boots when I set UEFI in BIOS (and the ubuntu disk is removed, of course). And I think that is the problem, but I think I have to reinstall Windows when I want to disable UEFI...

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu. From the next reboot, a menu may appear which allows you to choose the OS.

Comment: I don't want to boot Ubuntu, and Windows is already the first boot option, but Windows crashes while booting. But only if the Ubuntu disk is connected...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows. It's a GUI tool for managing EFI boot loaders, and it should enable you to set Windows as the default boot option.

If you wanted to do the same thing in Ubuntu, you'd use the `efibootmgr` program: Type `sudo efibootmgr` to see the options, then use the `-o` option to set the boot order as desired.